# R DataFrame leading NA's shift

Tags: r

I've searched longer than I'd like to admit for shifting leading NA's to the end.
Got close with a few stack questions "Cut out outer NAs in R","Rotate a Matrix in R","na.locf remove leading NAs, keep others [closed]" as well as looking over na.trim function in zoo package.  Essentially I want to turn this:

```
D <- matrix(c(1:9), 3)
D[2,1]<- NA
D[3,1]<- NA
D[3,2]<- NA
D <- as.data.frame(D)
```

into this:

```
D1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,5,9),
       V2 = c(4,8,NA),
       V3 = c(7,NA,NA))
```

Any help is as always, much appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort(...,  na.last = T)` within row-wise `apply`:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(D, 1, sort, na.last = T)))
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  4  7
#2  5  8 NA
#3  9 NA NA
```

---

### Update

To avoid ordering non-`NA` entries, you can do:

```
# Revised sample data
D <- matrix(c(1:9), 3)
D[2,1]<- NA
D[3,1]<- NA
D[3,2]<- NA
D <- as.data.frame(D)
D[2,2:3] <- c(8, 5);
D;
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  4  7
#2 NA  8  5
#3 NA NA  9


as.data.frame(t(apply(D, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))))
#V1 V2 V3
#1  1  4  7
#2  8  5 NA
#3  9 NA NA
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without sorting from lowest to highest?  I still need the original order of data.  For instance if the 8 was in front of the 5 in row two I would still want 8, 5, NA

Comment: @ALMDude Sure, I've just revised my answer to address you comment. Please take a look.